# Installed OpenCV on Mac and using it on Xcode but it throws library not found errors

Tags: xcode, opencv

I followed this tutorial for the installation process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o62iO8SssZk

So I've done all the steps and it works except when I try to execute main.cpp, build fails and it throws the error: library not found for -lHalf-2_4.24.0.0

So I tried to find this library and add it to the project but I couldn't even find such a library in the folder and don't know how to solve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.